# Hibernate JPA issue doesnt apply IS-A Relationship of table at some times

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, hql, jpql

I have a Parent Table A and extended Child tables B and C

ex:

```
public class A {
private Long id;
//getters setters//
}

public class B extends A{
 private String name;
//getters setters//
}
```

now at my repository,

```
public interface B extends JpaRepository<B, Long> {
@Query("select a from A a")//--This works
B getAll()

@Query("select a.id, b.name from A a join a.B b")//-- This doesn't
B getSpecificCols()
}
```

I need an explanation since "B is an A" that's why getAll() works
how come getSpecificCols() isn't working?

Error is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to <package>.B
```

BTW I'm using Hibernate Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading documentation what I needed all along was to put constructors in my entity/table where you put what specific parameters you need.

Answer (score 2):

The query returns a long (a.id) and a string (b.name). The interface assumes that you return an entity (B). The returned id cannot be cast into a B, so you get a `ClassCastException`. If you want individual fields you can return `List<Object[]>`, where each record will be an array with id and name. Or you can use a projection (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

By the way, does the first query really work when there are A entities in the database that are not B entities, for example if A also has a subclass C? It looks plain wrong to select the base class and return the derived class without filtering. I would select from B to return B.

Comment: Yes It works, B extends A so B is also an A I something from A that's why I extended it to B (My lead required me to do it that way and should only return an Object not a List<Object[]> which is I already tried), what's bugging me is I tried querying "select a.id from A a" from class A's interface and it works selecting only the Id and it's properties yet with B it doesn't which doesn't make any sense. anyways i'll look into your suggestion. Will accept this as an answer thanks!.